# android LInear layout centering a button

Tags: android

In Linear layout am trying to center the button but i cant what is the coding for centering the button suggestion please

this is my Linear layout

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="98"
                android:layout_height="58"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="S T A G E"
                android:id="@+id/stage1"
                android:background="#65f077cc" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thank you in advnce

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_" is not complete, should be "wrap_content", but this is just a typo here I guess?

Comment: i 've correct  it still not getting the button center

Comment: You put the `gravity="center"` to button, you should put it to LinearLayout as in my answer

Comment: Why a HorizontalScrollView inside ScrollView!!!? :|

Comment: now that you added the parent layouts.. keep adding `android:gravity=center"` to them all if it still wont work.

Comment: because in that layout am gonna add many objects in vertical form and gonna scroll them in horizontal so i given those views.

Comment: Did you get it working? I have added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First remove things that might affect it. Orientations is best to be define at as high level as possible, like in your parent `LinearLayout`. From `Button`, remove (for now, add later if you still think you want them) `android:orientation="horizontal"`, and `android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"`.

Also fix the height of the button to be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

To `LinearLayout`, add

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Here is a good read on the differences of `gravity` and `layout_gravity`: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.fi/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html

Additionally, `fill_parent` is deprecated, so you should switch to `match_parent` instead, where appropriate.

Edit: the final layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="98"
            android:layout_height="58"
            android:text="S T A G E"
            android:id="@+id/stage1"
            android:background="#65f077cc" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. Add weight to the button.
android:weight="1"

Comment: try to use relativeLayout if LinearLayout is not compulsion and use layout_gravity property

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to center an item in the center of the screen  use a Relativelayout** because linear layout is use for displaying items in a row.

**Like This**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stage1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#65f077cc"
    android:text="S T A G E" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**If you want to center an item in the center of a row use the below sample.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stage1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#65f077cc"
    android:text="S T A G E" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Although if you are strict with **linear layout ONLY** than you can try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stage1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#65f077cc"
    android:text="S T A G E" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why is linear layout only for rows?

Comment: thank you Fasiha.Its working.sorry for late response.I just need an clarification that why its  not possible in linear layout

Comment: LinearLayout means you can align views one by one. i used the word row because views are align one after another. that's why relative layout in more efficient for  this scenario. where as i updated my answer and add a linear layout with center property.